# Can use old csrf-token when old session is invalid

Tags: csrf-token

In my server, I create session by userId, create and valid csrf-token by userId too, like this:

```
session = createSession(userId)

csrf-token = createToken(userId) 

validateToken(userId,csrf-token)
```

In this case, if one user login in, he gets session-1 and csrt-token-1.
Then he logout and login angin, he gets session-2 and csrt-token-2, but he can still use csrt-token-1 to do post request with session-2, because session-2 has the same userId as session-1 (csrt-token-1 is not expired).

My question is:

Can I use an old crsf-token which is not expired to do request with new session?

csrt-token-1 can protect my server from csrf-attack, but I feel this is not right.

Comment: The approach is flawed, tokens are randomly generated bits. The idea of generating them based on userId practically makes them pointless (anyone who has access to the id, which is usually public, although this is also a problem, can generate a valid token)

Comment: In method `createToken(userId)` I generate a string by userId-randomString-timestamp, and then encrypt this string as token, so others cannot generate token by userId.
If I not use userId to generate token, how can I konw this token belongs to this user? Maybe I can use session-id to generate token?

Comment: So this randomString and the timestamp must be stored in the user's session for validation (and expiration checking) to be possible. in this case, when changing session, the old token becomes invalid. The use of signatures for validation (in the JWT scheme) makes tokens session-independent. In that case, you can also include the session ID in its body.

Comment: it's a good idea